# Storing URLs and Environmental Variables in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I was wondering what the proper protocol is for storing things such as URL endpoints, Client IDs and Client Secrets, in Xamarin. The information stored would need be reached by many classes across the solution. Right now, I am storing them as properties in a class within a portable class library. Not sure if this is right or if there is a better way.

Comment: Do you have any concerns in regards to the approach you're currently using? Is safety and reverse engineering a concern? If not, then your current solution should be viable.

Comment: Kinda, the API I am using is open, so reverse engineering to get the keys and such wouldn't be a catastrophe. I am open to hear what else you had in mind though :)

Comment: For things like `URL endpoints`, I tend to lean towards using an xml/json file that I load at runtime (either from a bundled/cached file or https based resource). Debug builds can contain a set of development endpoints (i.e. locally hosted services), CI/test builds can a use test endpoints, alpha/beta could be different and production/app store can use the production end points..... this of course if highly app/infrastructure dependent.  Any "private/secret" user info that is generated and consumed at runtime, store it in the in the OS provided trust manager, keystone, etc..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/best-security.html https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Comment: For data that you need to protect, you could consider using the `Keychain` (iOS) or `Keystore` (Android). For less secure data, you can consider using `NSUserDefaults` or `SharedPreferences`. In any case, it would be sensible if you encrypted the data before storing it and decrypt it when required.

Comment: IMHO securing or encrypting url endpoints is a waste of time. Even if they are https, the url can be obtained with any http proxy. ClientId usually refers to the type of client (mobile, web, etc). Why would you want to secure that?. The important thing to secure/obfuscate is the user token and/or refresh token (in case you use oAuth. If not, you should!), but that´s a different matter. I would store URL endpoints wherever you feel is right. I personally do it normally in a static constant that changes its value with conditional compiler symbols (DEBUG, RELEASE, STORE)

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of settings: app settings, and user settings.
App settings are data that an app creates and manages. It can include data such as fixed web service endpoints, API keys, and runtime state. App settings are tied to the existence of the app and are only meaningful to that app.

Xamarin.Forms includes a persistent dictionary that can be used to store settings data. This dictionary can be accessed using the Application.Current.Properties property

Xam.Plugins.Settings library, available from NuGet. This library provides a consistent, type-safe, cross-platform approach for persisting and retrieving app and user settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/configuration-management